# Change color of each html division one by one (every 500ms)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was planning to make a sorting visualiser game on Vanilla JS and HTML/CSSS3 but I am having difficulty with the dom manipulations w.r.t. particular time interval.
Lets say I want to change the colour of each div after every 500ms, how I am gonna change the color of each division

```
  <body>
    <div class="color">Division 1</div>
    <div class="color">Division 2</div>
    <div class="color">Division 3</div>
    <div class="color">Division 4</div>
    <div class="color">Division 5</div>
  </body>
```

```
  <script>
    var color = document.querySelectorAll(".color");
    console.log(color[0]);

    setTimeout(change, 3000);

    function change() {
      color[0].style.background = "green";
    }
  </script>
```

```
  <style>
    div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: aqua;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: use `setInterval` and store the index.

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want to cycle them (only 1 green at a time) or do you want them to come on one after the other (so at the end they're all on)?

Comment: I want them to come one after the  other  without changing the green colour of previous divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the background color via js just create a css class with your styling. then use querySelector to grab the first color div without the updated green class. once all divs have been updated the interval will clear itself

```js
setInterval(change, 3000);

function change() {
  const el = document.querySelector(".color:not(.green)");
  el != undefined && el.classList.add('green');
  el == undefined && clearInterval(change);
};
```

```css
.color {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="color">Division 1</div>
    <div class="color">Division 2</div>
    <div class="color">Division 3</div>
    <div class="color">Division 4</div>
    <div class="color">Division 5</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: OPs requirement: "*I want them to come one after the other without changing the green colour of previous divs*" - which this clearly doesn't do, just cycles all of them

Comment: @freedomn-m, you are correct i didnt see that clarification prior to my answer. it has now been modified to cycle through the elements one at a time

Comment: Well, OP accepted your answer and you didn't get a downvote for it - but your updated solution is pretty nice.